# Set a default value for INSERT statement PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

I know this should be a simple question, i have the following insert statement which is inserting values captured via a form, all works well but i would also like to add a default value to a column not on my form(lets say language for example), i don't want to add the default value via the database, as i have two forms that are coming together to the one table.

```
$stmt = DB::query(Database::INSERT,
    'INSERT INTO `my_products` (`first_name`, `initial`, `last_name`, `street`)
    VALUES (:first_name, :initial, :last_name, :street)');                                                      

$stmt->param(':first_name', $post['first_name']);
$stmt->param(':initial', $post['initial']);
$stmt->param(':last_name', $post['last_name']);
$stmt->param(':street', $post['street']);
```

Is there a way to specify a default value via the above?

Comment: Since you have two forms that should be saved into the same table use HIDDEN type form fields in your forms and accept them as usual parameters.

Comment: You could use my tiny library [ValueResolver](https://github.com/LapaLabs/ValueResolver) in this case, check my answer   please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with this?

```
$stmt = DB::query(Database::INSERT,
    "INSERT INTO `my_products` (`first_name`, `initial`, `last_name`, `street`, `myColumn`)
    VALUES (:first_name, :initial, :last_name, :street, 'my default value')");
```

Or possibly:

```
$stmt = DB::query(Database::INSERT,
    'INSERT INTO `my_products` (`first_name`, `initial`, `last_name`, `street`, `myColumn`)
    VALUES (:first_name, :initial, :last_name, :street, :my_column)');

...
$stmt->param(':my_column', 'my default value');
```

Comment: Number 2 works for me, thanks! I had done something similar but was leaving the $post in by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You could use my tiny library [ValueResolver](https://github.com/LapaLabs/ValueResolver) in this case, for example:

```
$stmt->param(':my_column', ValueResolver::resolve($post['first_name'], 'default')); // returns 'default' if $post['first_name'] is empty
```

and don't forget to use namespace `use LapaLabs\ValueResolver\Resolver\ValueResolver;`

There are also ability to typecasting, for example if your variable's value should be `integer`, so use this:

```
$id = ValueResolver::toInteger('6 apples', 1); // returns 6
$id = ValueResolver::toInteger('There are no apples', 1); // returns 1 (used default value)
```

Check the [docs](https://github.com/LapaLabs/ValueResolver) for more examples